# implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0' dependency not working

Tags: android-glide

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0' dependency not working in some android projects . I have tried different ways like compile(''){ transitive=true}   but it is not working .

Answer (score 0):

Use following dependency .

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'.